# any way to stop div sliding in Chrome Developer Tools?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to stop a div animation on a site that i don't have control to. The main idea is to use kimono lab, to capture certain texts on the wevsite, But i can't move my mouse fast enough.

the site is : http://www.healthtap.com

i know i can write python code to just scrape the site. But i'm just curious on how to accomplish this using kimono and chrome's developer tools. I can disable javascript on the dev tools, but it will also disable the JS from kimono.

Comment: You can temporary disable javascript inside the dev tools. Maybe this would be enough. After this you can inspect the DOM.

Comment: if i disable JS inside the dev tools, it will also disable the JS from kimono labs. I still need to use the JS from kimono. So, disabling won't work.

Comment: This is where the rotation happens https://edc1.healthtap.com/cdn/83a524/javascripts/perf/homepage.js

But I see no methods to stop/pause it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand the question, but I am not sure, so bear with me.

I believe you want to stop the slides so that you can use kimono:

Try using this in the console:

```
jQuery('.blue_buttons a:eq(0)').click();
```

That will simulate the click on the first slide button. Change 0 to 1, 2, 3, 4. and so on to get the next slides. I don't see any timeouts that would start the rotation again.

Comment: aaah, good move!! The thing is this will work only in standalone mode. When i run kimono, it actually run on kimono server, and it uses the health tap site as input, and the button isn't even clickable anymore. I'm going to mark this as an answer anyway. I don't think this is easily doable using kimonofy. I will just write code to scrape this site.

Comment: Yeah, I never used kimono before, so I am not sure how it works. It does look like a really interesting way to scrape content though.

Answer (score 1):

Open up the Developer Tools (F12 or right click somewhere blank and click “inspect”)
Click the three little dots in the top right corner, and then click settings (or just press F1 with the Developer Tools window selected)
Check “Disable JavaScript”

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add `Load` breakpoint in `Event Listener Breakpoints`.

Go to `Sources -> Event Listener Breakpoints -> Load -> load` and tick this option.